# Problem creating a google script to share a document (based on hour and day in the week)

Tags: google-apps-script

sorry in advance I don't really know how to code in Apps Script.
I'm trying to create an automatic sharing function for a document, the purpose is to change the access of the document, from "edit" to "view only" for a certain time on every week.

My example: My document X, shared with my colleague Y, should be in "view only" for him from tuesday 18:00pm till the next day 07:00am, then it goes back into "edit" mode and he can write on the document.

Here you can find the code I tried:

```
function shareDocument() {
var documentId = "DOCUMENT_ID"; // Replace with the ID of the document I want to share
var emailList = ["emailofY@example.com", "emailofZ@example.com"]; // List of email addresses to share with
var today = new Date();
var dayOfWeek = today.getDay(); // 0 for Sunday, 1 for Monday, ..., 6 for Saturday
var currentHour = today.getHours();

var document = DocumentApp.openById(documentId);

if (dayOfWeek === 2 && currentHour >= 18) {
// Switch to "read-only" mode
var editors = document.getEditors();
for (var i = 0; i < editors.length; i++) {
  document.removeEditor(editors[i]);
}
for (var j = 0; j < emailList.length; j++) {
  document.addViewer(emailList[j]);
}
Logger.log('Switched to "read-only" mode.');
} else if (dayOfWeek === 3 && currentHour < 6) {
// Switch back to "editor" mode
var viewers = document.getViewers();
for (var k = 0; k < viewers.length; k++) {
  document.removeViewer(viewers[k]);
}
for (var l = 0; l < emailList.length; l++) {
  document.addEditor(emailList[l]);
}
Logger.log('Switched back to "editor" mode.');
} else {
Logger.log('No action needed for sharing.');
}
}
```

I don't know why but it doesn't work and I can't find why... maybe the problem is the "trigger" I choose?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your question, I cannot understand the detail of `but it doesn't work`. Can I ask you about the detail of it? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: @Tanaike, I said that it doesn't work because when I tried to share a document with my colleague mail adress, he was able to "edit" the document, but today (based on the parameters I choose) he wasn't supposed to be able to "edit" it, just be in "view only" mode. I'm not sure if it's clear, but basically the code in itself don't have any "error" but it just doesn't do what it's supposed to do!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill., again. I cannot understand `it just doesn't do what it's supposed to do`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: @Tanaike I will try to explain it differently. If the code work, my colleague should be able to edit the document (write something on it) until tuesday by 7pm at this time the mode of the document change into "view only", few hours later it should be editable again (by 6am on wednesday) and my colleague should be able to edit the document again. But today If I try (we are tuesday after 7pm) my colleague can still edit the document... I don't know why the document's mode haven't change from "editable" to "view only" while we are tuesday at 9pm.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Your expected situation of `it just doesn't do what it's supposed to do` is as follows. You want to set the permission of Google Document to "editor" only from 06:00 to 18:00 on Tuesday. You want to set the permission on the Google Document to "viewer" on all days except for that. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Tanaike , almost!  "viewer" : from tuesday 18:00pm to wednesday 06:00am and "editor" the rest of the days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- Only from 18:00:00 on Tuesday to 06:00:00 on Wednesday, you want to set the permission of Google Document to "Viewer" for the users of `emailList`.
- For other days, you want to set the permission of Google Document to "Editor" for the users of `emailList`.

In this case, I think that the time-driven trigger is useful for your situation. In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Usage:

In this answer, in order to manage the time-driven trigger, I use [a Google Apps Script library TriggerApp](https://github.com/tanaikech/TriggerApp). I created this library for simply managing the time-driven triggers.

##### 1. Install library

You can see how to install the library at [here](https://github.com/tanaikech/TriggerApp#1-install-library).

##### 2. Sample script

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor and set the variables of `documentId` and `emailLis` to your actual situation. And, please run `sample`.

```js
const changePermission_ = (method) => {
  const documentId = "DOCUMENT_ID";
  const emailList = ["emailofY@example.com", "emailofZ@example.com"];

  const file = DriveApp.getFileById(documentId);
  const obj = { "Editors": "Viewers", "Viewers": "Editors" };
  file[`get${obj[method]}`]().forEach(e => file.revokePermissions(e));
  file[`add${method}`](emailList);
}
const setPermissionToEditor = _ => changePermission_("Editors");
const setPermissionToViewer = _ => changePermission_("Viewers");

// Please run this function.
function sample(e) {
  const now = new Date();
  if (!e) {
    const weekDay = now.getDay();
    const hour = now.getHours();
    if ((weekDay == 2 && hour >= 18) || (weekDay == 3 && hour < 6)) {
      console.log("setPermissionToViewer")
      setPermissionToViewer();
    } else {
      console.log("setPermissionToEditor")
      setPermissionToEditor();
    }
  }
  now.setMonth(now.getMonth() + 1);
  const obj = [
    { ownFunctionName: "sample", functionName: "setPermissionToViewer", everyWeek: ["Tuesday"], atTimes: ["18:00:00"], toDay: now.toISOString() },
    { ownFunctionName: "sample", functionName: "setPermissionToEditor", everyWeek: ["Wednesday"], atTimes: ["06:00:00"], toDay: now.toISOString() },
  ];
  const res = TriggerApp.setEventObject(e).installTriggers(obj, console.log);
  console.log(res);
}
```

- When `sample` is run, the permission of the Document is set by the current date time. And, the next trigger is installed. When the trigger is run, the function of `setPermissionToViewer` or `setPermissionToEditor` is run.
- For example, when the now is "2023-08-01 00:00:00", the trigger process is as follows. This trigger is continued to be run without finishing. When you want to set the finish date time, please set it to `toDay`. And, in this case, your timeZone is used.

  ```json
  [
    { triggerTime: Tue Aug 01 2023 18:00:00 GMT+0900 (Japan Standard Time), executeFunction: 'setPermissionToViewer' },
    { triggerTime: Wed Aug 02 2023 06:00:00 GMT+0900 (Japan Standard Time), executeFunction: 'setPermissionToEditor' },
    { triggerTime: Tue Aug 08 2023 18:00:00 GMT+0900 (Japan Standard Time), executeFunction: 'setPermissionToViewer' },
    { triggerTime: Wed Aug 09 2023 06:00:00 GMT+0900 (Japan Standard Time), executeFunction: 'setPermissionToEditor' },
    { triggerTime: Tue Aug 15 2023 18:00:00 GMT+0900 (Japan Standard Time), executeFunction: 'setPermissionToViewer' },
    ,
    ,
    ,
  ]
  ```
- If you want to change the function name of `sample`, also please modify `ownFunctionName` in `obj`. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [TriggerApp (Author: me)](https://github.com/tanaikech/TriggerApp)
- [Easily Managing Time-Driven Triggers Using Google Apps Script (Author: me)](https://medium.com/google-cloud/easily-managing-time-driven-triggers-using-google-apps-script-7fa48546b4e7)